# iOS segue between view controllers with navigation controllers

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to pass a value using a storyboard segue. My storyboard goes Navigation Controller -> View Controller -> View Controller.

I'm sure that everything else is set up correctly. I don't have any errors before testing on the simulator but am then presented with:

> [RunViewController2 topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109d6a0b0
>   2014-03-06 22:54:31.261 RunPal[22381:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RunViewController2 topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109d6a0b0'

The code I am using in my first view controller is:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"passSegmentedValue"]){

      UINavigationController *nav = [segue destinationViewController];
       RunViewController2 *runVC2 = (RunViewController2 *)nav.topViewController;

       run2VC.weekIdentifier = ((UISegmentedControl*) sender).selectedSegmentIndex;
   }
}
```

Comment: The exception clearly says that the you are trying to send message topViewController to the RunViewController2. Could you make sure that the segue leads to the navigation controller.

Comment: post your storyboard screenshot please

Comment: [Storyboard](http://imgur.com/VCgjDYY)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"passSegmentedValue"]){

       RunViewController2 *runVC2 = [segue destinationViewController];

       run2VC.weekIdentifier = ((UISegmentedControl*) sender).selectedSegmentIndex;
   }
}
```

Comment: Tried this and am now getting the following errors:

`code`
2014-03-07 14:14:50.894 RunPal[39342:70b] -[UIButton selectedSegmentIndex]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109b75150
2014-03-07 14:14:50.930 RunPal[39342:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton selectedSegmentIndex]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109b75150'
`code`

Comment: your sender is a UIButton, and not UISegmentedControl. Can you post a screen shoot of your view ?

Comment: I need to have the push to the second view controller happen when the Start Run button is pressed and this should pass over the value selected on the segmented control too. Thanks.

Comment: OK ! 1st you need an IBOutlet for your segmented control : ctrl+drag  your segmented control to your VC to create a IBOutlet property. then in your code : `run2VC.weekIdentifier = self.yourSegmentedControlPropertyName.selectedSegmentIndex;`

Comment: Just tried it and it doesn't seem to be passing the value over. I've programmed it to set a label to the value of the segment index but it just appears as 0.

Comment: PS : I've check your storybord one more time, and you probably have others issue. Why did you have 2 navigation controller, why did you have a segue back from your "about" ViewController ?

Comment: It works now! Thanks for your help. I used to have a tab navigation but got rid of it, is there no need for the Info VC to have a navigation controller? There is a push segue from the info button in the Run VC that goes to it.

Comment: You should have in runViewController2.h : @property (nonatomic) NSInteger weekIdentifier;  + your label IBoutlet. In runViewController2.m, put in your -(void)viewDidLoad, self.yourLabelPropertyName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.weekIdentifier];. Now It should Work. FYI, at Segue time, the view is still not load, so you could not init a property attached to the view. Hop this will help to solve your issues.

Comment: Oh, we alway have one comment late... No, you need 1 navigationController for your whole project (You can need more, but this will be for future : big projects).

Answer (score 0):

Check what the type of your destination controller by using the `po` command in your debug console by using a break point for the line `RunViewController2 *runVC2 = [segue destinationViewController];`.

This will certainly show you that destination is not of type `UINavigationController` and so invoking the topViewController method will lead to a crash. Your destination view controller is probably of type `RunViewController2` actually like Armand DOHM mentioned.